# What should be done for deploying EJB 2.1 in Jboss AS 6.0

Tags: jboss6.x

What is the configuration one has to do for deploying EJB 2.1 in Jboss AS 6.0?
Kindly refer to links, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any explicit configuration needed. JBoss AS 6 officially only supports the Java EE web profile (which doesn't include EJB 2.1 at all), but in practice they have implemented the full stack and EJB 2.1 beans should just work.

That said, if at any way possible, try to avoid EJB 2.1. It's a bloated, nasty and heavy-weight technology that's literally from another era. For any new development EJB 3.1 or even 3.0 is highly recommended.

Comment: hi,Thanks for your quick reply, can you tell what should i do to make EJB 2.1 work in jboss 6.0, because we have developed our application in EJB 2.1, we can't migrate everything at a time, we have to do slowly. So tell me exactly what should i do to make it work.

Comment: ya i tried, but its throwing exception, kindly refer the link http://community.jboss.org/message/603809#603809

Comment: hi, kindly go through the link, jboss 6 is supporting EJB2.1 ansd its working  fine, http://community.jboss.org/message/603868#603868. thanks for your replies,